# How to split a Python loop going over excel columns into several different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, openpyxl

This is an update to my other post. I had to include extra details such as an image of the excel file type i am working with and add more detailed explanations.

I have an excel spreadsheet ([Scaled down sample of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3u1k.png)) with the total number of patents filed in 19 countries. I want to read this data into excel and separate the cell values under 'Total' into 19 blocks of cell values to represent the number of patents filed by law firms (each row) in each country. I might add the column for law firms later on.

## Goal

My goal is to break the loop over an excel column when there is an empty cell, record any values the loop has iterated through before the empty cell to a an empty list. Then for the loop to continue from where it last stopped (cell.value = None) and then break again at the next instance of None and record this new area of cell.values in another empty list. This needs to happen over the whole list and I will probably end up with a list of list.

Whats the best way to modify my code so that i can do this, preferrably with openpyxl. Do i need to make a list of lists? Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

```
#Read PCT rankings project ratified results
#Beta

import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('PCT rankings project ratified results.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('PCT by IP firms')

row_counter=sheet.max_row
column_counter=sheet.max_column

print(row_counter)
print(column_counter)

my_list=[]
for row in range(4,sheet.max_row +1):
    patent=sheet['I'+str(row)].value
    print(patent)
    my_list.append(patent)
    if patent == None:
        break
if None in my_list:
    my_list.remove(None)
print(my_list)[enter image description here][1]

my_list2=[]
for row in range(2,sheet.max_row +1):
    country_name=sheet['A'+str(row)].value
    if isinstance (country_name, str):
        #print(country)
        my_list2.append(country_name)
print(my_list2)
```

Comment: I needed to make a new post to make it clearer. They are different, not copies.

Comment: You should edit the original post, not create new ones. Anyway, it's not clearer.